# I am getting an error that "Post 404 [conversation update]" in microsoft bot ? how to resolve that?

Tags: botframework

POST 404 [conversationUpdate]
I am getting the error only when I have used web API, else working properly.

Comment: Can you post your code for your bot?

Comment: Please add your code and more explanation what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this code error in the Bot Framework Channel Emulator when you enter wrong the endpoint.

I think you are entering wrong the endpoint. I had the same error in this case, when I entered "server + /api/messages", it worked.

For example: http://localhost:3333/api/messages

If this solution doesn`t work, please give more information, your post is very general.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. I resolved it by using http://localhost:3979/api/messages instead of http://127.0.0.1:3979/api/messages